# Try Catch finally in C# - can I somehow say if exception is thrown go to end, or to start otherwise continue? IWould like to stop and start new file?

Tags: c#, md5, try-catch-finally

sorry if its noob question but I am System Administrator, not developer, but willing to learn more :)

I am writing small console application in C# to verify backup files with MD5 hash. I Actually wrote and it works fine, except it counts error files as good because application works after try-catch even if exception is catch. I will paste part of the code with try catch finally block, my question is can I by any chance in "finally" say "if exception is thrown log filename and exception and go to beginning (start calculating next file) else if stream !=null ....continue Computing hash?
Thank you very much
Ervin

Here is my code in try-catch-finally block

```
        try
        {
            myHash = null;
            myFileMd5 = null;
            stream = new FileStream(myFilename, FileMode.Open);
            
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException)

        {
            File.AppendAllTextAsync(hashList, "The file " + myFilename + " or directory cannot be found." + "\n");
            badcounter++;
        }
        catch (DirectoryNotFoundException)
        {
            File.AppendAllTextAsync(hashList,"The file " + myFilename + "or directory cannot be found." + "\n");
            badcounter++;
        }
        catch (DriveNotFoundException)
        {
            File.AppendAllTextAsync(hashList, "The drive specified in 'path' is invalid." + "\n");
            badcounter++;
        }
        catch (PathTooLongException)
        {
            File.AppendAllTextAsync(hashList, "'path' exceeds the maximum supported path length." + "\n");
            badcounter++;
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {
            File.AppendAllTextAsync(hashList, "You do not have permission to access this file: " + myFilename + "\n");
            badcounter++;
        }
        catch (IOException e) when ((e.HResult & 0x0000FFFF) == 32)
        {
            File.AppendAllTextAsync(hashList, myFilename + " " + "Sharing violation." + "\n");
            badcounter++;
        }
        catch (IOException e) when ((e.HResult & 0x0000FFFF) == 80)
        {
            File.AppendAllTextAsync(hashList, myFilename + " " + "The file already exists." + "\n");
            badcounter++;
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            File.AppendAllTextAsync(hashList, $"An exception occurred:\nError code: " +  $"{e.HResult & 0x0000FFFF}\nMessage: {e.Message}" + myFilename + "\n");
            badcounter++;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (stream != null)
            {
                myFileMd5 = md5.ComputeHash(stream);
                stream.Close();
            }
        }
        return (myFileMd5);
    }
```

Comment: Can't you just put a condition on `badCounter`? If it's greater than 0 then that means at least one exception got thrown.

Comment: fwiw I would increment `badcounter` before your other `File` operations just in case those fail too.

Comment: I would also use "using" for file streams. Then it removes the need for you to close it.

Comment: Is this code part of a loop where you try to process more than one file? If yes could you post your attempt to handle this loop?

Comment: Typically, you'd encapsulate in its own method the code you want to treat atomically, returning an error value. Then you can check the error value and do the rest if there's no error. Alternatively, you just let the exception propagate out to the caller. It's not clear at all what _specifically_ you need help with here.

Comment: The `finally` block isn't typically meant for a continuation of your code's flow. Instead, it's used to finalize things whether an exception was caught or not, such as disposing of objects (e.g. close/dispose a stream), etc.

Answer (score 3):

Usually it is not a good practice to use the finally block to continue your processing logic. The finally block is executed in any case even if there is an exception catched or not. So your logic inside the finally block needs to be protected by the stream open failure and, not probable, but what if the same ComputeHash throws an exception?

So, I would move the logic inside the try block. If there is an exception the ComputeHash is not executed anyway and with the using statement you don't need to close the stream.

```
// This class will be used to comunicate back to the caller the result of the hash
// Try to avoid using too many global variables if possible. They make your code very
// unmaintenable.
public class ComputeStatus
{
   public string errorText {get;set;} = "";
   public byte[] hash {get;set;}
}

public ComputeStatus MyComputeHash(string filename)
{
    ComputeStatus status = new ComputeStatus();
    try
    {
        using var stream = new FileStream(myFilename, FileMode.Open);
        status.hash = md5.ComputeHash(stream);
        return status;
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException)
    {
        string error = $"The file {myFilename} or directory cannot be found.";
        // This can now be moved outside the method as well and done just one
        // time by the caller in case of error text.
        // File.AppendAllTextAsync(hashList, error);
        status.errorText = error;
    }        
    ..... all the other catch blocks follow

    return status;
}
```

Now the calling code just need to check if the ComputeStatus instance returned contains an error message or not. Let the error counting be handled at that level.

Comment: Technically you don't need the return in the try block, the one at the end of the method will be hit in either case.

Comment: @Damian70 correct, it's an habit of mine. I find more readable to look just at the "normal" flow to understand the logic and then process the "what if" path. Something akin to the "arrow code" problem. https://blog.codinghorror.com/flattening-arrow-code/ (point 4)

Answer (score -1):

Something like this should work:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    List<string> files = new List<string>();
    files.Add(@"C:\file1.txt");
    files.Add(@"C:\file2.txt");
    files.Add(@"C:\file3.txt");
    foreach(string myFilename in files)
    {
        //... your existing code...
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not address OP's problem.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand the problem. It appears he is simply trying to loop through multiple files, handling errors, generating a hash, without ending the process when an error is hit. Short of writing the entire thing for the OP, the general idea is covered... I thought. Maybe I am missing something...?

Comment: Exactly, I have original files stored in some folder tree and I am making daily backup of those files on network with the same folder structure. What I want is to make a console app that will take original\file.txt calculate hash and backup\file.txt calculate hash, and check if they are equal, and write it to file, if the program has I/O error or file does not exist it should write it to log and take next file......